# Will there be any client side(java code) changes if the server switches from SSL to TLS

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

I have a client code which connects to a server configured with SSL. Now the server is switching from SSL to TLS for better security, completely disabling SSL. Would there be any code level changes on the client side?

This is my code :

```
public String callService(String _data, String _signature) {
    SSLContext sslcontext = null;
            String response = null;
    try {
        sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

        sslcontext.init(new KeyManager[0],
                new TrustManager[] { new DummyTrustManager() },
                new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

    SSLSocketFactory factory = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();

    String data = _data;
    String signature = _signature;
    String urlParameters = "data=";
    try {

        urlParameters = urlParameters + URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8")
                + "&signature=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    try {
        URL url;
        HttpsURLConnection connection;
        InputStream is = null;

        url = new URL("https://**.**.**.**/TLS/Inquiry");

        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);
        connection.setHostnameVerifier(new DummyHostnameVerifier());

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        osw.write(urlParameters);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

        is = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        response = in.readLine();

        System.out.println("Output " + response);
        is.close();
        in.close();

    } catch(ConnectException connExp) {
                connExp.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

            return response;        
}
```

Comment: Do you use a specific framework for handling data transport on client side? If yes, which is it?

Comment: What client code? It's possible to build version dependencies into anything. If your client code is correctly written you won't have a problem, but without seeing your code it is impossible to be definitive. @ SpaceTrucker Unless his framework introduces a JSSE implementation of its own, which is unlikely if not impossible, your question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There might be implications depending on the version of java the client is using. Different versions of Java will have different default protocols. Please refer the below link to refer to the defaults for Java 8,7 and 6.

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

If you are disabling the version of protocol on the server that is the default version that your client is using, then the client will start failing. This can be rectified by changing the default protocol - by using the system property 'https.protocols'.